# Combine xml and XSL

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

This is a follow on question from an earlier question [Decoding base64 image data using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837293/decoding-base64-image-data-using-xslt)

I would still like to send the end user a file, xml and have it transformed into beautiful looking html using the style sheet
however I would like to send the end user ONE single file. One single XML file that works standalone (no calls to any server or any other dependencies)

One single XML file with the style sheet embedded, but I don't know if/how to do this
consider the xml from that question

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2016080901.xsl"?>
<catalogue>
    <item>
        <item_id>1234</item_id>
        <item_desc>hi-fi sanio</item_desc>
        <price>12.50</price>
        <image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAAAzCAYAAADigVZlAAA</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>4614</item_id>
        <item_desc>lace work</item_desc>
        <price>1.50</price>
        <image>QN0lEQVR4nO2dCXQTxxnHl0LT5jVteHlN+5q+JCKBJITLmHIfKzBHHCCYBAiEw</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>614</item_id>
        <item_desc>bicycle</item_desc>
        <price>150</price>
        <image>jVteHlN+5q+JCKBJITLmHIfKzBHHCCYBAiEwlEQVR4nO2dCXQTxxnHl0L</image>
    </item>
</catalogue>
```

and the transforming xsl

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>data URI test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalogue">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]" mode="header"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="header">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/*" mode="header">
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/*">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/image">
    <td>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{.}"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

how can I combine the two so that I can have a single resulting file to give to the end user? so that they can view the resulting output
without any dependencies (other than their web browser of course, assuming IE11 as the browser of choice for the end user)

Regards

Comment: Why don't you simply do the conversion to HTML and send the user the resulting HTML file?

Comment: In reality I can't I'm updating a legacy application's output. I don't have access to the application all I get is the xml and I really want to improve what I (and others )see in the browser, that's why I'm adding the style sheet, but often when I send it on to other users they don't have the style sheet or they have it in the 'wrong' directory, basically I just want to make it simple and easy to use, not having to copy files here and there to make the resulting xml output look good

Comment: Embedding XSLT in XML is described in the XSLT specification, although I don't know how widely supported it is. Check out this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132106/using-inline-xslt-for-an-xml-file

Comment: I don't recommend embedding the stylesheet into every XML you send to the client. That's a waste of bandwidth. When you send them separately, the client can take advantage of caching, which saves bandwidth and will ultimately be faster.

Comment: @user595985 If you cannot process the source XML into HTML, then how on earth will you be able to process it into another XML with the stylesheet embedded into it?

Comment: @micheal.hor257k, a little context, the end users (field reps) get the xml file sent to them(email/ftp/attachment), they 'read' it often using notepad. I think if they got an xml and an xsl the viewing experience is better in their browser. But sometimes they don't get the xsl, or place xsl in the 'wrong' location/folder so it looks garbled in the browser. If I can combine both the xml & xsl into one file then it would be look nice in the browser and no fiddling to find & place the xsl in the 'right' folder. It would just work. Reps are not connected to any server(i.e mainly offline)

Comment: @user595985 You're not answering my question. "*If I can combine both the xml & xsl into one file then it would be look nice in the browser ...*" That is correct - and for best results, the combined file should be HTML.

Comment: sorry if I missed the point @micheal.hor257k. Let me try again, the application generates xml as its output. I am able to tweak the resulting XML a little, as its legacy I cannot have the application generate HTML, I guess its historical "Its staying XML because its always been XML.." not a good reason but I'm paraphrasing what I'd be told in suggesting changing the output that is emailed/ftpd/attached to end users from the 'familiar' XML to HTML. I can only get away to updating the existing XML adding a style sheet, adding a node here or there. For the moment that's the constraint.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*tweak the resulting XML a little*", Either you are able to perform an XSL transformation on it, or you're not. If you are, then there is no reason why you should not produce HTML as the result. In fact, there's every reason to produce HTML and no reason at all to produce this esoteric XML with embedded XSLT that only a few browsers can read. If you're not, than I don't see how you can produce either one. I also don't see why you could not run an XSL transformation on the resulting XML using a tool other than your "legacy application".

Comment: P.S. Please spell my username correctly, so I get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome seem to support inserting the stylesheet into the XML and referencing it using e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#id-of-stylesheet-root-element"?>`, here is the previous example adapted to use that mechanism:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalogue [
  <!ATTLIST xsl:transform
     id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#style"?>
<catalogue>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" id="style">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="xsl:transform"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>data URI test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalogue">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]" mode="header"/>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="header">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/*" mode="header">
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/image">
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{.}"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>

    <item>
        <item_id>1007</item_id>
        <item_desc>test</item_desc>
        <price>3.14</price>
        <image>iVBORw0KGgoAA
AANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0l
EQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6
P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>1234</item_id>
        <item_desc>hi-fi sanio</item_desc>
        <price>12.50</price>
        <image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAAAzCAYAAADigVZlAAA</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>4614</item_id>
        <item_desc>lace work</item_desc>
        <price>1.50</price>
        <image>QN0lEQVR4nO2dCXQTxxnHl0LT5jVteHlN+5q+JCKBJITLmHIfKzBHHCCYBAiEw</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <item_id>614</item_id>
        <item_desc>bicycle</item_desc>
        <price>150</price>
        <image>jVteHlN+5q+JCKBJITLmHIfKzBHHCCYBAiEwlEQVR4nO2dCXQTxxnHl0L</image>
    </item>
</catalogue>
```

However Microsoft IE and Edge report an error during XSLT transformation and simply render all text nodes so for those browsers the approach does not seem to be useful. Creating the HTML on the server and sending out that seems safer.

As for creating the XML with embedded XSLT programmatically, with the commercial editions (i.e. PE or EE) of Saxon 9 it is possible using the following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet which takes the URI of the stylesheet to embed as the parameter `sheet-uri`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:dtd="http://saxon.sf.net/dtd"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-Alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon dtd axsl"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="sheet-uri" as="xs:string" select="'test201608140301.xsl'"/>

    <xsl:param name="sheet" select="doc($sheet-uri)"/>

    <xsl:param name="sheet-id" as="xs:string" select="'sheet'"/>

    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <saxon:doctype>
            <dtd:doctype name="{name()}">
                <dtd:element name="{name()}" content="ANY"/>
                <dtd:element name="{name($sheet/*)}" content="ANY"/>
                <dtd:attlist element="{name($sheet/*)}">
                    <dtd:attribute name="id" type="ID" value="#REQUIRED"/>
                </dtd:attlist>
            </dtd:doctype>
        </saxon:doctype>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="#<xsl:value-of select="$sheet-id"/>"</xsl:processing-instruction>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$sheet/node()" mode="include-sheet"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*" mode="include-sheet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="$sheet-id"/>
            <axsl:template match="{name()}"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I seem to be missing something here: how exactly would you create this file?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I am not sure what you want to point out with your question, I have created that file like any other XSLT I write, in a text editor. Whether that is an option for the poster of the question is not clear, but at least the answer demonstrates how to embed the XSLT for the transformation in the sample input of the transformation.

Comment: As I said, I seem to be missing something here. I am under the impression that OP periodically generates a dynamic XML output from some application and attaches a static stylesheet to it when sending it out. In order to send out a combined document like the one shown in your answer, they must produce it from the XML source output by the application - and they must do it every time they want to update their users.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you said... "Firefox and Chrome seem to support inserting the stylesheet into the XML and referencing it using e.g. <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#id-of-stylesheet-root-element"?>"..but not IE.